# Is there any difference in meaning between "go along with someone" and "come along with someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Would you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *go along with someone* and *come along with someone*? For example:

> You can **go along with** me to the movies tomorrow if you want.
>
> You can **come along with** me to the movies tomorrow if you want.

Dictionaries such as [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go-come-along) say that they mean the same thing, but do they mean exactly the same thing? Is there a nuance of difference between them?

Comment: Longman doesn't exactly say that they mean the same, just that _along_ can be used with either _go_ or _come_. If the invitation is to an outing 'with me', I would use _come_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Thanks you for the commen. I'd like you to clarify something. So if I say "you can go along with," that means you can come to the same place but not with me, right?

Comment: "You can go along with Mary" means that you can accompany Mary to some place (probably without me).

Answer (score 1):

It's the same difference as "go" and "come" generally, which is "come" indicates *accompaniment with or getting closer to the speaker*.

"Go" can indicate everything, including these meanings of "come", but "come" is preferred in those contexts.

So in this context, where it's an invitation to do something together, "come" is strongly preferred, though "go" isn't wrong.

Comment: Also be aware that in AmE *go along with*  can be used casually to express agreement with an idea or concept.  *They said it would cost more and what could we do other than **go along** with that?*  https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-along-with#:~:text=(go%20along%20with%20someone%E2%80%8B,agree